# Is it all right to say "one one hundred" when you actually mean to say "one percent"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, colloquial-language

This is from BBC about space and planets [Space questions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IC_AWX0v2Y) (see:27:05-27:40)

The presenter says;

**"Its atmosphere is one one hundred the pressure of Earth."** which doesn't make sense.

However, the English (UK) subtitles show it like this:

**"Its atmosphere is 1/100 the pressure of Earth."**, which definitely makes sense.

But, I wonder is it all right to say **"one one hundred"** to mean **"one percent"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are mis-hearing, but the automatic captioner has (this time) got it right.  She says "one one-**hundredth** the pressure of Earth" or "1/100". That does mean one percent. The blend from /d/ to /θ/ is tricky for native speakers too. Note that 3/100 would be "three hundredths" (with an even trickier blend /dθs/) and not "three one-hundredths"

Fractions can be read using ordinal numbers for the denominator (third, fourth, fifth etc). So 2/3 is two-thirds, 5/8 is five-eighths.  It is rarer to use this with, for example 234/547, but in principle that could be read as "two hundred (and) thirty-four, five hundred (and) forty-sevenths". It gets confusing! But with round numbers (eg hundredth, thousandth, millionth) it is quite common. 3/1000 is "three thousandths".

<sub>The autocaptioner doesn't always get it right.  It has changed "called corundum" to "cuckoo random" earlier!</sub>

Comment: that is completely new to me as a non-native speaker. They never taught this to us at school. Well, they did teach about fractions, for instance "1/3 is pronounced one-third", but they did not mention about such a confusion in understanding could take place when it comes to "1/100". Thanks James.

Comment: @yunus we can say any fraction in words by using an ordinal number (if 3 or over) for the lower part of the fraction (the denominator) so that 1/47 is 'one forty-seventh', 1/1,000,000 is 'one millionth', and 3/51 is 'three fifty-firsts'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yes michael thanks. I knew how to say fractions, usually the simple ones, but never guessed the sound /θ/ at the end would be unheard and confuse us, when we are listening.

Comment: @yunus - with hundredths we can avoid the problem by speaking of it as a percentage, e.g. 6/100 is 'six percent'.

Comment: the  /θ/ is pronunced, but it's not very clear on the sound track.  It has rather merged with the /d/ sound, but it is there. It is a tricky blend and she isn't speaking especially slowly.

Comment: I think that a native speaker, who possibly already knows that the Martian atmosphere has a lower pressure than Earth's, would (considering the repeated 'one') know that a fraction was being pronounced and mentally 'hear' the -th ending.